# How to edit text font in JEditorPane

Tags: java, text, fonts

I have a `JEditorPane` where it is loaded a txt file. I want to have a button that changes the font size. I have found about `StyledEditorKit` but i am not able to use it. I am very new to java and its kind of difficult for me.

```
     public JFrame init() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pagination");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
    editor.setEditorKit(this);

    editor.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
        public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
            if (!isPageBreakInsertion ) {
                ( (StyledEditorKit) editor.getEditorKit()).getInputAttributes().removeAttribute(PAGE_BREAK_ATTR_NAME);
            }
        }
    });



    JMenu fontMenu = new JMenu("Font Size");
    for (int i = 48; i >= 8; i -= 10) {
      JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("" + i);
      // add an action
      menuItem
          .addActionListener(new StyledEditorKit.FontSizeAction(
              "myaction-" + i, i));
      fontMenu.add(menuItem);
    }
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.add(fontMenu);

    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    this.setHeader(createHeader());
    this.setFooter(createFooter());
    PageFormat pf = new PageFormat();
    pf.setPaper(new Paper());

    final PaginationPrinter pp = new PaginationPrinter(pf, editor);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(editor);

    frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);
    JToolBar tb=new JToolBar();
    JButton bPrint = new JButton("Print to default printer");
    bPrint.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            print(editor, pp);
        }
    });
    JButton bInsertPageBreak = new JButton("Insert page break");
    bInsertPageBreak.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            insertPageBreak(editor);
        }
    });

    File file = new File("uuu.txt");

    try {
        editor.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) editor.getDocument();

    // Create a style object and then set the style attributes
    Style style = doc.addStyle("StyleName", null);

    StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 30);



    tb.add(bPrint);
    tb.add(bInsertPageBreak);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 23, 665, 789));

    return frame;
}
```

This is my code so far. I have searched a lot for it but i cant find something that gives me a solution. Also, i dont know exactly how to use the `StyledEditorKit`.
Thank you.

I have to keep the following code

```
final JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
editor.setEditorKit(this);
```

because it creates the layout that i need, which is an A4 paper and sets the limits. Also i have to add that my class extends StyledEditorKit.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a JEditorPane where it is loaded a txt file.

For plain text you should use a `JTextPane`. JEditorPane is for HTML.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for a working example that allows you to change the font, color etc. of selected text in a JTextPane.

Comment: Is it possible that i include inside the JEditorPane a JTextPane? I have to keep the JEditorPane because it is connected with the pagination that is initialized in another class (another file).

Comment: @user3882720, No, you can't add a JEditorPane to a JTextPane. But the concept of using the Actions should still be the same.